# Is there a javascript/jquery implementation of a day-calendar scheduler like tungle.me

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, appointment

I'm looking for an implementation of a single-day calendar view - like a daytimer - and ideally allowing selecting a block of time by mouse / touch dragging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)'s week view.

http://josh3736.net/images/fullcal.png

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that runs on top of [EXT.JS](http://www.sencha.com/store/extjs/) called [Bryntum Ext Scheduler](http://bryntum.com/products/scheduler/) that does this. This is not some trivial piece of code - it is a complete calendar UI system that supports multiple views and complex data linking and events.

I've worked with EXT.JS and Scheduler and it is by far one of the best frameworks available. It may be overkill for simple projects - but for enterprise applications it is money well spent.

EXT.JS = $595

Scheduler = $350

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Like you said though, this might be overkill for my scope project